# Use ViewHolder element outside onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Is it possible to use ViewHolder element outside onBindViewHolder?

This is my adapter class

```
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val item = mValues[position]
            with(holder.mView) {
                tag = item
                txvTitle.text = item.title
                setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener)
            }
        }

   inner class ViewHolder(val mView: View) :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mView{})
```

If I have one function in adapter, how can I use `txvTitle`?

```
fun checkHashMapExists(hashMap: HashMap<Long, ABC>?, newValues: ArrayList<OT>){
      for(i in newValues){
         if(hashMap?.keys.toString().contains(i.id)){
             txvTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")) // txvTitle cannot resolved
         }
      }   
    }
```

**FragmentA**

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mAdapter.checkHashMapExists(hashMap,otList)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should not use `ViewHolder` outside `onBindViewHolder`. All UI-related code should be called inside `onBindViewHolder`. Prefer to call `notifyDataSetChanged` or other `notifyXXX` method to redraw your `RecyclerView` content.

Comment: I want to change txvTitle color when the function is called from fragment. How can I use notifyDataSetChanged in this case?

Comment: @JohnJoe Add `someField` to your adapter. When the function is called from fragment update value of `someField` and call `notifyDataSetChanged`. Inside `onBindViewHolder` you should respect `someField`. Like: `if(someField) { use color1} else {use color2}`

Answer (score 2):

Even though **I do not recommend using it**, you can call the following method to get the ViewHolder for data element at position `i`:

```
MyViewHolder holder = (MyViewHolder) mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
if(holder != null) {
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

Keep in mind what the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int)) says about that method:

> Return the `ViewHolder` for the item in the given position of the data set. Unlike `findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(int)` this method takes into account any pending adapter changes that may not be reflected to the layout yet. **On the other hand, if `notifyDataSetChanged()` has been called but the new layout has not been calculated yet, this method will return null since the new positions of views are unknown until the layout is calculated**.

Instead, **what I would do if I were you**, is to have an attribute in your model class that indicates which color its ViewHolder should use to display the `txtView.title` text.

Then, whenever you want to update the color of an element (or elements) in your RecyclerView, you can change that attribute of your model class and then call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 1):

The adapter has no way to know what `txvTitle` means, as it is specific to a single item in the `RecyclerView`.
Within a `ViewHolder` however, this property (if existent) is related to the view that is being "prepared".

Thus, updates to the view should only be done in the `ViewHolder` class.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork/reddit) example.
In this example, a separate class is created which extends `RecyclerView.Viewholder(view)`.
Within this class, a method called `bind` is defined, which is passed the object (or model) that is used to populate the view. 
The `create` method inflates the layout of the view to be drawn in the `RecyclerView`

Comment: I use `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in your adapter class which takes **[Higher order function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)** as parameter and then expose your `ViewHolder` object in that function to be used outside of **Adapter class**.

See how it can be done :

Let's say you've **Adapter class** as below

```
class Adapter {
    ...
    // Here we create object of our Higher order function
    var holderCallback: ((RecyclerView.ViewHolder?) -> Unit)? = null

    //Then We provide callback like below in onBindViewHolder method
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        ... Some binding stuff
        holderCallback?.let {
           it(holder)
        }
        ... even some more stuff
    }
}
```

And now we can access from outside *(In your case, from Fragment class)*

```
class Fragment {
    // Here we have adapter object
    ...
    //So, we get our callback like below from any method in here
    ...Inside some method where we receive callback
    adapter.holderCallback { viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder? -> //Here you've got ViewHolder object
        // Now do some amazing stuff here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to change text color of holder item based on that adapter method right?

Comment: Ya. How can I pass the two parameters from fragment to adapter class ?

Comment: Where are that both parameters? Are they at adapter class or at fragment class?

Comment: This line in FragmentA `mAdapter.checkHashMapExists(hashMap,otList)`

Comment: It seems I'm not able to understand your dilemma clearly.